# Shortcut to bypass all animations and go to next slide in Powerpoint?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, vba, macros

Is there a shortcut in Powerpoint instead of using the control panel or right-click menu to bypass animations and go straight to next slide?

Comment: Not directly related, but one shortcut is typing the slide number.  Of course, that isn't always realistic nor a real solution for you.

Comment: @nerdwaller One solution of creating an action button with hyperlink to next/previous slide on the Slide Master is there, but it would look awkward and make me too dependent on the mouse. I know that tip, but thanks anyways.